# Apache2 ldap auth security

Tags: apache, security

In my one of virutal hosts I have enable authentication by windows domain. Evertything works fine, but I have a question about security. Is the password stored in the configuration file is somehow encrypted during communication with domain? And another question, is the user domain password is encrypted to during communication? I will be grateful for answer.

Your faithfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you use plaintext LDAP, none of them will be encrypted. If you use SSL (be it with LDAPS or with STARTTLS), your passwords will be encrypted.

Comment: So, if I use certyficate from ca or self-signed, than ldap connection will be encrypted to?